# How to replace Kusto cluster rows (Azure Data Explorer) when ingesting from Azure Table Store

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-explorer

Using Azure Data Factory, I created a pipeline that ingests from source Azure Table Store to sink Kusto (Azure Data Explorer). The ingestion does an append to Kusto. However, I need to change this to do a set-or-replace ingestion rather than an append. I'd like to replace existing (PartitionKey, RowKey) rows found in my Kusto cluster with matching (PartitionKey, RowKey) from the Azure Table and append any rows where there is no match on (PartitionKey, RowKey). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Kusto only support Insert there wont be an update as per my knowledge..

Answer (score 0):

You can only append the rows to existing tables.
One way to achieve your scenario is by having one more column called SnapshotTime or similar name. Whenever you have the latest data for some partition or category, you can set this to latest timestamp. When querying you can take the latest from this timestamp for every category of the data.